# Thymeleaf unable to evaluate internationalized expression

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I am trying to achieve internationalization and I have the following html markup.

```
<p th:text= "${your_amount(${it.vm.getAmount})}"></p>
```

which generates html as

```
<p>Your Amount is: $</p>
```

`Your Amount is: $` is exactly what my internationalized string is.
Ideally the result should be.

```
<p>Your Amount is: $123.24</p>
```

The `it.vm.getAmount` sort of doesn't get executed. I have checked that there is a value present inside `getAmount` with the following

```
<p th:text="${it.vm.getAmount}"></p>
```

Which gives me a result as

```
<p>123.24</p>
```

Does thymeleaf consider `"$"` to be a special character while rendering and is there a way to work around that?

Comment: What is `your_amount`?  Is it a method that formats the localized text and amount? If so, please include the complete code for the method.  If not, please explain further..

Comment: Nope its just an internationalized string constant in my .properties file. There is no formatting.

Comment: In that case the syntax appears wrong.  Did you try something like `${your_amount}\$${it.vm.getAmount}`?

Comment: Thank you for the expression Jim I just gave that a shot and thymeleaf throws a TemplateProcessingException to this statement. Also I dont think the expression I am using is incorrect. I have used the same expression in my snippet multiple times successfully. I believe it has something to do with the presence of : $ in my string. I will probably remove that and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression:

```
<p th:text= "${your_amount(${it.vm.getAmount})}"></p>
```

is not valid syntax -- for many reasons.

1. `${}` expressions are never nested inside other `${}` expressions -- unless you are preprocessing.
2. If `your_amount` is a string, you cannot use it as a function `your_amount(...)`.
3. `it.vm.getAmount` shouldn't work -- unless you really have named your getter method `getGetAmount()`.  It should either be `it.vm.amount` or `it.vm.getAmount()`.

When I try your expression, I get this error:

`Method your_amount(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELContextMapWrapper`

If you just want to append different strings together, you should really be doing something like:

```
<p th:text= "${your_amount + it.vm.getAmount}"></p>
```

or

```
<p>
    <span th:text="${your_amount}"><span th:text="${it.vm.getAmount}">
</p>
```

or

```
<span th:text="|${your_amount}${it.vm.getAmount}|" />
```

Comment: Hi Metroids, thank you for the answer. All three of your solutions worked. Thanks a lot.